# Mathematica can not recognize the wanted element in a matrix when doing a numeric integral, even though it is plotted on the last step?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, numerical-integration

[image]
As shown, function 'TestF' is defined via interpolation and maps a number to a 4 by 4 matrix. Its (3,3) element is plotted at step 141, but not recognized in the numeric integration within the same range. How can that be possible?

The code with shorten data is following:

```
data={{0.843944, {{-3.4671*10^-17, 0., 
0., -3.5534*10^-16}, {0., -3.60717*10^-15, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
7.21434*10^-15, 0.}, {-3.5534*10^-16, 0., 
0., -3.64184*10^-15}}}, {0.907682, {{-0.0000120049, 0., 
0., -0.000123037}, {0., -0.00124899, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.00249798,
 0.}, {-0.000123037, 0., 
0., -0.00126099}}}, {0.97142, {{-0.000106935, 0., 
0., -0.00109597}, {0., -0.0111256, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0222511, 
0.}, {-0.00109597, 0., 0., -0.0112325}}}, {1.03516, {{0.000101995,
 0., 0., 0.00104534}, {0., 0.0106115, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -0.0212231, 0.}, {0.00104534, 0., 0., 
0.0107135}}}, {1.0989, {{0.0000295598, 0., 0., 0.000302955}, {0., 
0.0030754, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -0.0061508, 0.}, {0.000302955, 0., 
0., 0.00310496}}}, {1.16263, {{5.68556*10^-6, 0., 0., 
0.0000582707}, {0., 0.000591525, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -0.00118305, 
0.}, {0.0000582707, 0., 0., 
0.000597211}}}, {1.22637, {{1.72719*10^-6, 0., 0., 
0.0000177018}, {0., 0.000179697, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -0.000359394, 
0.}, {0.0000177018, 0., 0., 
0.000181424}}}, {1.29011, {{6.33575*10^-7, 0., 0., 
6.49344*10^-6}, {0., 0.0000659171, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -0.000131834,
 0.}, {6.49344*10^-6, 0., 0., 
0.0000665507}}}, {1.35385, {{2.62468*10^-7, 0., 0., 
2.69001*10^-6}, {0., 0.0000273072, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -0.0000546143, 0.}, {2.69001*10^-6, 0., 0., 
0.0000275696}}}, {1.41758, {{1.2021*10^-7, 0., 0., 
1.23202*10^-6}, {0., 0.0000125067, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -0.0000250133, 0.}, {1.23202*10^-6, 0., 0., 
0.0000126269}}}, {1.48132, {{5.84518*10^-8, 0., 0., 
5.99067*10^-7}, {0., 6.08132*10^-6, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -0.0000121626, 0.}, {5.99067*10^-7, 0., 0., 
6.13978*10^-6}}}, {1.54506, {{3.00555*10^-8, 0., 0., 
3.08036*10^-7}, {0., 3.12697*10^-6, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -6.25395*10^-6, 0.}, {3.08036*10^-7, 0., 0., 
3.15703*10^-6}}}, {1.6088, {{1.56645*10^-8, 0., 0., 
1.60544*10^-7}, {0., 1.62974*10^-6, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -3.25948*10^-6, 0.}, {1.60544*10^-7, 0., 0., 
1.6454*10^-6}}}, {1.67253, {{8.4205*10^-9, 0., 0., 
8.63009*10^-8}, {0., 8.76069*10^-7, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -1.75214*10^-6, 0.}, {8.63009*10^-8, 0., 0., 
8.84489*10^-7}}}, {1.73627, {{4.6251*10^-9, 0., 0., 
4.74022*10^-8}, {0., 4.81195*10^-7, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -9.62391*10^-7, 0.}, {4.74022*10^-8, 0., 0., 
4.8582*10^-7}}}, {1.80001, {{2.60284*10^-9, 0., 0., 
2.66763*10^-8}, {0., 2.708*10^-7, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -5.416*10^-7, 
0.}, {2.66763*10^-8, 0., 0., 
2.73403*10^-7}}}, {1.86375, {{1.48338*10^-9, 0., 0., 
1.5203*10^-8}, {0., 1.54331*10^-7, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -3.08662*10^-7, 0.}, {1.5203*10^-8, 0., 0., 
1.55814*10^-7}}}, {1.92749, {{8.54432*10^-10, 0., 0., 
8.75699*10^-9}, {0., 8.88951*10^-8, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -1.7779*10^-7, 0.}, {8.75699*10^-9, 0., 0., 
8.97496*10^-8}}}, {1.99122, {{4.97424*10^-10, 0., 0., 
5.09805*10^-9}, {0., 5.1752*10^-8, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -1.03504*10^-7, 0.}, {5.09805*10^-9, 0., 0., 
5.22495*10^-8}}}, {2.05496, {{2.92371*10^-10, 0., 0., 
2.99648*10^-9}, {0., 3.04183*10^-8, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -6.08366*10^-8, 0.}, {2.99648*10^-9, 0., 0., 
3.07107*10^-8}}}, {2.1187, {{1.72959*10^-10, 0., 0., 
1.77264*10^-9}, {0., 1.79947*10^-8, 0., 0.}, {0., 
0., -3.59894*10^-8, 0.}, {1.77264*10^-9, 0., 0., 1.81677*10^-8}}}};
TestF:=Interpolation[data];
Plot[TestF[x][[3, 3]], {x, Sqrt[4 Ms^2 + k.k], M\[Phi] + \[Mu] + Norm[k] + 3 gV T}, PlotRange -> All]

NIntegrate[TestF[x][[3, 3]], {x, Sqrt[4 Ms^2 + k.k], M\[Phi] + \[Mu] + Norm[k] + 3 gV T}]
```

Comment: There is not enough information provided to recreate the issue or determine how to remedy it.

Comment: Edit your question to include copy and pate-able code rather than just an image of the code. We also need your data to work with.

Comment: Without being to run your code, I suspect `NIntegrate` is attempting to do some precalculation on your function and can’t. This may help: `nfunc[x_?NumericQ] := With[{mat = TestF[x]},mat[[3,3]]]` and then `NIntegrate[nfunc[x],{x,yourLimit1,yourLimit2}]`. But, I am not sure if it will help without the other definitions.

Comment: thx Craig, your solution solves the problem!

Comment: 1. Your sample is still incomplete. (Experienced user may be able to guess what you mean, though. ) 2. You should put more effort in creating a simplified sample. The issue is fully reproducible with the following simple sample: `func = Interpolation@Table[{i, {{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}}}, {i, 5}];NIntegrate[func[x][[1, 1]], {x, 1, 5}]`. 3. This topic is well discussed in FAQ: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/1871

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the values for the several constants, I will use the `{xmin, xmax}` from the data for both plotting and integration.

```
    {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]
    
    (* {0.843944, 2.1187} *)
    
    Plot[TestF[x][[3, 3]], {x, xmin, xmax},
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
    NIntegrate[TestF[x][[3, 3]], {x, xmin, xmax},
     MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

[image]

The warning message indicates that an integration was attempted before `x` was given a numeric value. After the symbolic integration failed, the numeric integration provided the result. To avoid the initial attempt at integration with symbolic `x`, define

```
    f[x_?NumericQ] := TestF[x][[3, 3]]
```

Then there is no warning message:

```
    NIntegrate[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
     MaxRecursion -> 20]
    
    (* -0.000527017 *)
```